# Disabilities in the Classroom

Tags: professorship, disability

Are there any special provisions provided for students who have schizophrenia (for example)? Is there an "adjustment" to grading? Or perhaps there is no adjustment to the grading process *per se*, but only to the due dates? Is there anyone here who has been in this type of situation?

Comment: Depends on the relevance of the disability to academic performance, on the severity with which the person suffers from the disability, the kind of assignment, the policies of the given school, and the laws of the country the school is located in (just to name a few things). Though I don't have the ability to vote myself, I advocate for closing the question as overly broad.

Comment: This question is not too broad on the ["entire book can be written on the subject"](http://academia.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) scale(although I can imagine chapters in books). There are some chatty elements to the question, but it has a nice short answer: consult the institutional office for disability services, as Anonymous suggests.

Answer (score 15):

Every university I have been affiliated with (in the U.S.) has had an office of disability services, tasked with evaluating individual cases and making (binding) recommendations to instructors.

If your university has such an office, then you should refer this case to them and avoid judgement calls of the type you ask about.

Comment: Often the policy is also to inform the instructor of any special needs that may be pertinent to grading. Usually, as a matter of fairness, the specific disability isn't given. Regardless, that informs the instructor that that student may need certain provisions (ex: taking the exam in room with services, etc.)

Comment: This answer is totally right. Those offices are trained in the relevant practical and legal issues, while individual professors are not.

Comment: I love that these offices exist for the very reason @NoahSnyder suggests. I am not trained on how physical, mental, and psychological disorders impact learning, nor do I know what the legal requirements are. The folks in my Disability Support Services office do. And if my students do not have the waiver from said office, I am not permitted to make any concessions.